# How to pass program arguments to java packager?

Tags: java, jvm, javapackager

I'm trying to create a native executable out of a .jar file I have locally. All looks fine except that I'm currently executing the jar file with an argument (`abc`):

```
java -Dappbase=http://localhost:80/getdown/xyz/ -jar getdown-1.7.1.jar abc
```

This is what I'm using to generate my native image:

```
javapackager \
  -deploy -BjvmProperties=appbase=http://localhost:80/getdown/xyz/ \
  -native \
  -outdir result \
  -outfile sample \
  -srcfiles getdown-1.7.1.jar \
  -appclass com.threerings.getdown.launcher.GetdownApp
```

How to signal `javapackager` that I'd like it to run `com.threerings.getdown.launcher.GetdownApp` with `abc` as an argument?

Thanks

Comment: did you try -argument arg

    An unnamed argument to be inserted into the JNLP file as an <fx:argument> element.

Comment: Yes, argument works. I'm not using a JNLP so that's why I thought it would not apply to my case.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

Sources : 
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference002.htm

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference002.htm#CACIJFHB

```
 <fx:application name="Sample app"
    mainClass="test.MyApplication">
  <!-- unnamed arguments -->
  <fx:argument>Something</fx:argument>
  <!-- value with spaces that are generated at build time -->
  <fx:argument>JRE version: ${java.version}</fx:argument>
  <!-- example of value using a special character -->
  <fx:argument>true &amp; false</fx:argument>
 </fx:application>
```